# Node.js + Socket.IO on Heroku - File Downloading

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, socket.io

As my first Node.js project, I've been building a reporting app for my work where people can search and then download the results to their computer as a CSV.

To accomplish this, I've been using Socket.IO to pass the JSON data back to my application.js file on a button click event. From there I use the json2csv module to format the data.

Here's where I run into issues...

1. I know Heroku uses Ephemeral File Storage (which should be fine since I only need the file to be on the server for the session anyway and the added cleanup is nice), however my file exists check comes back positive even though I can't see the file when I run

   ```
   heroku run bash
   ls
   ```
2. Since I'm using Socket.IO (as far as I can tell, anyhow) the normal request and response callback function parameters aren't available. Can I set the headers for the CSV using `data.setHeader()` which is the socket function callback instead of `response.setHeader()`? Do I need to break out that event listener from the sockets and run it directly from the `app.get`?

   Here's the code I have that takes the JSON data from the event and formats it based on my searches:

   ```
   socket.on('export', function (data) {
       jsoncsv({data: data, fields: ['foo', 'bar'], fieldNames: ['Foo', 'Bar']}, function(err, csv) {
           if (err) console.log(err);
           fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) {
               if (err) console.log(err);
               console.log('File Created');
           });
          fs.exists('file.csv', function (err) {
               if (err) console.log(err);
               console.log('File Exists, Starting Download...');
               var file = fs.createReadStream('file.csv');
               file.pipe(data);
               console.log('File Downloaded');
          });
       });
   });
   ```

**UPDATE**

Here's the actual client-side code I'm using to build and send the JSON as an event. The exact event is the `$('#export').on('click', function () {});`.

```
server.on('listTags', function (data) {
    var from = new Date($('#from').val()), to = new Date($('#to').val()), csvData = [];
    var table = $('<table></table>');
    $('#data').empty().append(table);
    table.append('<tr>'+
                    '<th>Id</th>' +
                    '<th>First Name</th>' +
                    '<th>Last Name</th>' +
                    '<th>Email</th>' +
                    '<th>Date Tag Applied</th>' +
                  '</tr>');
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
        var dateCreated = new Date(data[i]['DateCreated']);
        if (dateCreated >= from && dateCreated <= to) {
            data[i]['DateCreated'] = dateCreated.toLocaleString();
            var tableRow = 
            '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + data[i]['ContactId'] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data[i]['Contact.FirstName'] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data[i]['Contact.LastName'] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data[i]['Contact.Email'] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data[i]['DateCreated'] + '</td>' +
            '</tr>';
            table.append(tableRow);
            csvData.push(data[i]);
        }
    });
    $('.controls').html('<p><button id="export">Export '+ csvData.length +' Records</button></p>');
    $('#export').on('click', function () {
        server.emit('export', csvData);
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use response headers more easily with an http server (and with http you can also send the search query to the server). As a sidenote tip: instead of creating a file and then creating a readstream from it, why don't you directly create a stream, pipe that to `data` and write the csv variable from it? `var stream = new stream.Writeable(); stream.pipe(data); stream.write(csv, 'utf8', function(){console.log('done')});` [reference](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_new_stream_writable_options)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know that was possible so I'll give it a try. Would I still need to set the headers of the file? Otherwise I am kind of tied into using Socket.IO at this stage in the development cycle, though I am not sure that it is strictly necessary for what I need it for.

Comment: How are you handling the download on the client side? Browsers like it if you send the file with the correct MIME type (in your case `text/csv`). If you are just running a simple webpage and if your server already has an http server for handling that webpage I recommend to use HTTP. It is pretty easy to pipe a stream to the client, and you can also encode it (to save bandwith).

Comment: Updated original post with client side data to show how the data is built and then emitted back to the server.

Comment: As far as I can tell from "break out of the event listener and set response.setHeader()" you mean set the headers of the http page you sent before? That isn't going to work as that is another request. Socket.io doesn't work with headers. If you can also provide the code that receives the data from the readstream we can see whether you need socket.io or if you'd better stick to http.

Comment: What I meant was moving the 'export' listener out from under the `io.sockets.on()` function to it's own `app.get()` to run directly off the http server so I would have access to the request, response parameters (Not sure that's possible). However if I did that wouldn't I lose access to all the data within `io.sockets.on()`? I might be confused here or not understanding, but there's no "readstream", I'm trying to pass an object to the server and then it's creating a writestream (the csv file) from it for the browser to download to the user's computer; nothing is being uploaded to the server.

Comment: you are right, there is a big misunderstanding here. The callback from your http server `app.get` represents **one** request (think about one document). So when you send the requested HTML document and call `res.end()` (to tell the browser that this is the end of the file). So you will not be able to send the file over that. What I mean is that you just scrap out the socket.io system and then use a normal HTTP request. So from the browser you would create an http request, and send the object as a stringified header. On the server you can then check if the header exists, and do the formatting

Comment: ... and send that. I am also questioning the reason for directly using express, as that won't learn you that much about how the HTTP server in node works. Let me know what you think so I can give you an adapted answer.

Comment: Not sure where you see I'm using express; I'm not. I've got socket.io interfaced with the regular HTTP server as [shown here](http://socket.io/#how-to-use). From what I read, I do need socket.io to be able to emit events from the client back to the server, which I need for more than just exporting the data.

Comment: `app.get` usually refers to express. Socket.io does indeed use such kind of events, but you can also put that into an HTTP header. Still, the comment above about the function representing **one** request applies. From your reference, usage of app.get within socket.io means the usage of express. Look for the header _Using with the Express web framework_. Furthermore, I am able to provide you a good answer, but that will be without using socket.io, and just use plain HTTP requests.

Comment: If you've got a way to achieve the same behavior as what I've got without using socket.io I'd be happy to hear it, thanks.

Comment: I am going to write an answer for you containing just that.

Comment: Just to mention that I have posted an answer 2 days ago, as you are new user I would like to point out that when you think an answer is correct and helped solving your problem, you should accept it, so if other users have the same problem and find this question, they can easily see the answer that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As you point out yourself Heroku's file system can be a bit tricky.
I can help with your question (1), and that is that you are not connected to the *same* virtual machine (dyno) that your application is running from. When you run `heroku run bash` you come to a clean filesystem with the files that are needed for your app to run, and the `run` command is running (as opposed to the `web` process you have specified in your Procfile).

This makes sense when you consider that one of the advantages using Heroku is that you can easily scale up from 1 node to several when needed. But you would still expect `heroku run bash` to work the same way when you have 10 web nodes running with your code. Which one should you then be connected to? :)

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#an-example-one-off-dyno for some more details.

Hope this is helpful.
Best of luck!

/Wille

Answer (score 0):

So instead of using socket.io, we are just going to use an http server. I have a lot of code for you, as it is partially stripped of my own http server, and should of course also serve files (eg. your html, css and js files).

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var location = path.join(__dirname, url.parse(req.url).pathname),
        ext = location.split('.').slice(-1)[0];
    if (req.headers['request-action']&&req.headers['request-action'] == 'export'&&req.headers['request-data']) { //this is your export event
        jsoncsv({data: req.headers['request-data'], fields: ['foo', 'bar'], fieldNames: ['Foo', 'Bar']}, function(err, csv) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
                res.writeHead(404, {'content-type':'text/plain'});
                res.end('Error at jsoncsv function: ', err);
                return;
            }
            res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/csv');
            var stream = new stream.Writeable();
            compressSend(req, res, stream); //this is the equivalent of stream.pipe(res), but with an encoding system inbetween to compress the data
            stream.write(csv, 'utf8', function(){
                console.log('done writing csv to stream');
            });
        });
    } else {//here we handle normal files
        fs.lstat(location, function(err, info){
            if(err||info.isDirectory()){
                res.writeHead(404, {'content-type':'text/plain'});
                res.end('404 file not found');
                console.log('File '+location+' not found');
                return;
            }
            //yay, the file exists
            var reader = fs.createReadStream(location); // this creates a read stream from a normal file
            reader.on('error', function(err){
                console.log('Something strange happened while reading: ', err);
                res.writeHead(404, {'content-type':'text/plain'});
                res.end('Something strange happened while reading');
            });
            reader.on('open', function(){
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', getHeader(ext)); //of course we should send the correct header for normal files too
                res.setHeader('Content-Length', info.size); //this sends the size of the file in bytes
                //the reader is now streaming the data
                compressSend(req, res, reader); //this function checks whether the receiver (the browser) supports encoding and then en200s it to that. Saves bandwidth
            });
            res.on('close', function(){
                if(reader.fd) //we shall end the reading of the file if the connection is interrupted before streaming the whole file
                    reader.close();
            });
        });
    }
}).listen(80);
function compressSend(req, res, input){
    var acceptEncoding = req.headers['Accept-Encoding'];
    if (!acceptEncoding){
        res.writeHead(200, {});
        input.pipe(res);
    } else if (acceptEncoding.match(/\bgzip\b/)) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip' });
        input.pipe(zlib.createGzip()).pipe(res);
    } else if (acceptEncoding.match(/\bdeflate\b/)) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Encoding': 'deflate' });
        input.pipe(zlib.createDeflate()).pipe(res);
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, {});
        input.pipe(res);
    }
}
function getHeader(ext){
    ext = ext.toLowerCase();
    switch(ext) {
        case 'js': header = 'text/javascript'; break;
        case 'html': header = 'text/html'; break;
        case 'css': header = 'text/css'; break;
        case 'xml': header = 'text/xml'; break;
        default: header = 'text/plain'; break;
    }
    return header;
}
```

The top part is interesting for you, especially inside the first if. There it checks if the header `request-action` is present. This header will contain your event name (like the name `export`). The header `request-data` contains the data you would otherwise send over the socket. Now you might also want to know how to manage this client side:

```
$('#export').on('click', function () {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'localhost');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('request-action', 'export'); //here we set that 'event' header, so the server knows what it should do
    xhr.setRequestHeader('request-data', 'csvData); //this contains the data that has to be sent to the server
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onloadend = function(){//we got all the data back from the server
        var file = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: 'text/csv'}); //xhr.response contains the data. A blob wants the data in array format so that is why we put it in the brackets
        //now the download part is tricky. We first create an object URL that refers to the blob:
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        //if we just set the window.location to this url, it downloads the file with the url as name. we do not want that, so we use a nice trick:
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = 'generatedCSVFile.csv' //this does the naming trick
        a.click(); //simulate a click to download the file
    }
});
```

I have tried to add comments on the crucial parts. Because I do not know your current knowledge level, I have not added a comment on every part of the system, but if anything is unclear feel free to ask.